# Reading specific value from a tag with same name but different values

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am working on a python program that reads an XML file from a website API. I have attached a small example of the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KSG">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="3.33 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1208"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KXJ">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="6.40 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1211"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KXK">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="5.00 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1211"/>
</dbReference>`
```

I want to create a dictionary with the id and the value from the chains (e.g. {"7KSG" : "1-1208"}). I am using Beatifulsoap and ElementTree to read the tags and extract the value, but the same tag name has other different values (e.g., "EM", "5.00A"), so I have no idea how to extract the values of the chains.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [How to ask in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Info on [XML](https://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/XML/A_Quick_XML_Primer.htm) and [How to parse xml](https://lxml.de/parsing.html).

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: do you know that you can use also other values - ie. `type` - `find("property", {"type": "chains"})`. You should read ALL documentation for `Beatifulsoap` because it has many useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should read FULL documentation for `BeatifulSoap` because it has many useful functions.

```
item.find('property', {'type': 'chains'})
```

---

Full working example

```py
text = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KSG">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="3.33 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1208"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KXJ">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="6.40 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1211"/>
</dbReference>
<dbReference type="PDB" id="7KXK">
<property type="method" value="EM"/>
<property type="resolution" value="5.00 A"/>
<property type="chains" value="A/B/C=1-1211"/>
</dbReference>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('dbreference')  # it has to be lowercase `dbreference`

for item in all_items:
    id_ = item['id']
    chains = item.find('property', {'type': 'chains'})
    chains = chains['value'].split('=')[1]
    print(id_, chains)
    print('--')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Important is to use lowercase name `dbreference`

```
soup.find_all('dbreference')
```

Comment: First, thank you for the reply. I have read the Beatifulsoap documentation before asking a question here. It is really good indeed. I tried some codes, this one it is an example:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('P0DTC2.xml')
pdb_and_chains = {}

for i in tree.iter("dbReference"):
    pdb_id = i.find(attr={'id'})
    chains_values = [x.text for x in i.find_all('value')]
    pdb_and_chains[pdb_id] = chains_values

When I used BeatifulSoap, I call as a .xml file (BeatifulSoap("file.xml", "xml") and I haven't lowercase the "dbReference". Maybe that was my mistake.

Comment: BS can use different parser and for `html.parser` it has to be lowercase - it treats it as HTML tag. Maybe for other parses will work `dbReference`